# Should Proto.Actor ActorSystem.ShutdownAsync() stop all actors?

Tags: proto.actor

I was expecting the ***ActorSystem.ShutdownAsync()*** stop all actors before finishing returned Task, but this doesn't seem to happen. Does anyone know how I should terminate the ActorSystem correctly? I'd like all the actors to get called *IDisposable.Dispose()*.. Thank you for any ideas!